# Mutex in Python 2.6? Make Sure Only One Instance of the .exe Runing

Tags: python, python-2.6

I have a python 2.6 program used in windows (py2exe), I need to make sure it will there will be only one running checking the docs for python2.6 it says Mutex Is gone? What should I do to make sure it runs only one instance of the program? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @BasicWolf nobody gave there a simple nice answer... & Outdated I tested 1 of them it didnt work

Comment: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/474070-creating-a-single-instance-application/ ?